# How to make tkinter button raised before executing command

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Am trying to make GUI app which compulsory you have to select one of `predict` button before the number entered will be printed to the terminal,if none of `predict`button is selected the should print out`select predict button to proceed`.

In pseudecode something like:

```
def check:
    now = new.get()
    if no lotto_button is selected:
        print("select predict button to proceed")
    else:
        print(now)
```

But having  challenges:

1:when i select one predict button both buttons raised.

2:How to make the predict compulsory to be selected before the content in the entry will  be printed.

```
import tkinter as tk



def terminal():
    now = new.get()
    print(now)

def start_func():
    lotto_button.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)
    lotto_button1.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)



def stop_func():
    lotto_button.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)
    lotto_button1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


new = tk.StringVar()
en = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=new).pack()


lotto_button = tk.Button(root, text="predict one", command=start_func)
lotto_button.pack(side="left")
lotto_button1 = tk.Button(root, text="predict two", command=start_func)
lotto_button1.pack()


tk.Button(root, text="print number", command=lambda :[stop_func(), 
terminal()]).place(x=150, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you and your advice to do is welcome.

Comment: You should probably be using [RadioButton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm) widgets for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for making it compulsory for picking, you can define a flag in outermost scope (in same level as `root = tk.Tk()`) so that you can see in your functions if it's set or not like:

```
isPredicted = False
```

And as for disabling each button when one is picked, you can define your your `start_func` such that it takes button object (`lotto_button` or `lotto_button1`) as argument:

```
def start_func(button_object):

    global isPredicted
    isPredicted = True

    button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)
```

To be able to use this function, you need to configure your buttons in the following way, so that they pass themselves as the argument:

```
lotto_button.configure(command=lambda button_object=lotto_button: start_func(button_object))

lotto_button1.configure(command=lambda button_object=lotto_button1: start_func(button_object))
```

You should have `isPredicted` flag in your `stop_func` as well so that it unsets it:

```
def stop_func():

    global isPredicted
    isPredicted = False

    lotto_button.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)
    lotto_button1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)
```

As for your `terminal` function, you'd want to act based on the state of `isPredicted` so it needs to be defined as:

```
def terminal():

    global isPredicted

    if isPredicted:
        now = new.get()
        print(now)

    else:
        print("select predict button to proceed")
```

finally in your `"print number"` button you need to swap the order of the functions in lambda or `isPredicted` is always False as far as that button's command is concerned:

```
tk.Button(root, text="print number", command=lambda :[terminal(),
stop_func()]).place(x=150, y=300)
```

Your final code should look like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox



def terminal():

    global isPredicted

    if isPredicted:
        now = new.get()
        print(now)

    else:
        print("select predict button to proceed")

def start_func(button_object):

    global isPredicted
    isPredicted = True

    button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)



def stop_func():

    global isPredicted
    isPredicted = False

    lotto_button.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)
    lotto_button1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


new = tk.StringVar()
en = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=new).pack()

isPredicted = False


lotto_button = tk.Button(root, text="predict one")
lotto_button.configure(command=lambda button_object=lotto_button: start_func(button_object))
lotto_button.pack(side="left")
lotto_button1 = tk.Button(root, text="predict two")
lotto_button1.configure(command=lambda button_object=lotto_button1: start_func(button_object))
lotto_button1.pack()


tk.Button(root, text="print number", command=lambda :[terminal(),
stop_func()]).place(x=150, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But the is this thing i want to ask you, How can i make only one button be raised at a time because i can select both button at the same time and it will be raised

Comment: @NewpyBoi Nice! As others have mentioned radiobuttons may probably work better though.

Comment: Have tried the example @ Ethan Field provided but it applies the raised effect to the widget before you select it and it print the values set for the the radio buttons .

Comment: when you i removed the values and i select one of the radio button it select both.

Comment: @NewpyBoi You can put the same `if else` statement in `terminal` to your `start_func`, and put everything, except for `global isPredicted`, inside `else`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're clicking on one of the button prediction, both are raised because in your function start_func, you're configuring both.
Instead of configuring both of them you can bind an event click and getting the widget in start_func like this:

```
lotto_button = tk.Button(root, text="predict one")
lotto_button.bind('<1>', start_func)
lotto_button.pack(side="left")
```

And then in your start_func :

```
def start_func(event):
    w = event.widget 
    w.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)
```

About your second point, I'm not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: what i meant in my second point was that  if none of the prediction button is selected  should print "select predict button to proceed" in my terminal then break the printing process before you select one of them to print the number in the entry widget.

Comment: Oh I understand now, well. Check the answer of Nae which is really complete :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Radiobutton` widgets tends to be better for this sort of multiple choice processing.

`Radiobutton`s belong to *"groups"* which means that you can set them up so that one always needs to be selected by default. This means that you don't need to have any kind of error catching or display any sort of instruction to the user, it just intuitively works.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command(v, entry):
    print(v.get(), entry.get())

v = StringVar()
v.set(1)

entry = Entry(root)
rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Predict One", variable=v, value=1, indicatoron=0)
rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Predict Two", variable=v, value=2, indicatoron=0)
button = Button(root, text="Print Number", command=lambda:command(v, entry))

entry.pack()
rb1.pack()
rb2.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So we create a `StringVar()` which we use to define which `Radiobutton` widgets should be linked together and then we set it's value to `1` which is the value of the `"Predict One"` button. If the user presses the other `Radiobutton` then the value changes to `2` which means the first button "unpresses" and the value of the `StringVar()` is changed to `2`.